# How do I pass a random string from an array into views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

In my controller, I have an array of locations defined and I used `sample` to catch one of the random strings:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @location = ["England", "Scotland", "Wales", "Ireland"]
    random_location = @location.sample
  end
end
```

However, I don't know the code needed to display the one country in my browser.

Comment: Just use `<%= @location.sample %>` inside the view(index.html.erb). Then you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#sample`

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # @location i_var will be available automatically inside the corresponding
    # view of this action to the Index controller.
    @location = ["England", "Scotland", "Wales", "Ireland"]
  end
end
```

Now inside the view - `index.html.erb`

```
Country is <%= @location.sample %>
```